# Xamarin forms ios images not visible when deployment target is changed

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I'm working on a Xamarin forms project. The problem is in my Xamarin forms ios project when I set my deployment target as 6 all the images are visible when run on simulator, but when I change my deployment target to 9.0, none of the images are visible. I don't know how to resolve this issue.
with deployment target 9.0 i'm getting the below exception.

> Could not initialize an instance of the type 'UIKit.UIImage': the native 'initWithContentsOfFile:' method returned nil. It is possible
>   to ignore this condition by setting
>   MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Class.ThrowOnInitFailure to false.`at
>   Foundation.NSObject.InitializeHandle (System.IntPtr handle,
>   System.String initSelector) [0x00094] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/44931ae8/source/xamarin-macios/src/Foundation/NSObject2.cs:465
>   at UIKit.UIImage..ctor (System.String filename) [0x0002e] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/44931ae8/source/xamarin-macios/src/build/ios/native/UIKit/UIImage.g.cs:95
>   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ToolbarItemExtensions+SecondaryToolbarItem.UpdateIcon
>   () [0x00000] in
>   C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Extensions\ToolbarItemExtensions.cs:142
>   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ToolbarItemExtensions+SecondaryToolbarItem..ctor
>   (Xamarin.Forms.ToolbarItem item) [0x00018] in
>   C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Extensions\ToolbarItemExtensions.cs:113
>   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ToolbarItemExtensions.ToUIBarButtonItem
>   (Xamarin.Forms.ToolbarItem item, System.Boolean forceName) [0x00000]
>   in
>   C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Extensions\ToolbarItemExtensions.cs:28
>   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.NavigationRenderer+ParentingViewController.UpdateToolbarItems
>   () [0x0008f] in
>   C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Renderers\NavigationRenderer.cs:935
>   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.NavigationRenderer+ParentingViewController.ViewDidLoad
>   () [0x00044] in
>   C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Renderers\NavigationRenderer.cs:847
>   at (wrapper managed-to-native)
>   ObjCRuntime.Messaging:IntPtr_objc_msgSendSuper (intptr,intptr)   at
>   UIKit.UIViewController.get_View () [0x00030] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/44931ae8/source/xamarin-macios/src/build/ios/native/UIKit/UIViewController.g.cs:2716
>   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.NavigationRenderer.CreateViewControllerForPage
>   (Xamarin.Forms.Page page) [0x000ee] in
>   C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Renderers\NavigationRenderer.cs:401
>   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.NavigationRenderer+<OnPushAsync>d__44.MoveNext
>   () [0x0000a] in
>   C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Renderers\NavigationRenderer.cs:354
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw ()
>   [0x0000c] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/44931ae8/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/44931ae8/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/44931ae8/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/44931ae8/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter 1[TResult].GetResult ()
>   [0x00000] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/44931ae8/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:357
>   at Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage+<PushAsyncInner>d__90.MoveNext ()
>   [0x0009a] in
>   C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Core\NavigationPage.cs:358`

Comment: Try to clean and rebuild your solution, if that does not work, delete all the `bin` and `obj` folders from each project to clear the cache and try building again.

Comment: @Geraid Versluis I tried everything, but unfortunately It did not work